# Copy & Replace Windows non-booting Drive

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, clone

I'm looking for a good way to add a new, larger hard drive to a Windows 10 system and have it replace one of the drives that's currently defined.

Currently the computer has one physical drive with two partitions, C: and D:.  C: is the boot drive and D: has a variety of files on it including some Program Files.

I'm installing a new hard drive which I want to use as a replacement of the D: drive.  Then I plan to expand the C: partition to take up that space currently occupied by the D: partition.

Is it a simple matter of installing the new drive and accessing it temporarily as a new drive letter, coping all the D: files over to it, then deleting the current D: partition?  Or will that screw things up?

I currently have some programs installed to D: and have a user's home directory on D: as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method should in general work, but you need to ensure that there are no folders
on D that belong to Windows and which you cannot copy.

You should first disable temporarily the Recycle Bin on D, by right-click on its
desktop icon, click on D, and set it to "Don't move":

[image]

You may encounter other problems, so I suggest to not hurry with destroying
the D partition. After the copy, start Disk Management, give D another drive-letter,
then rename the new drive as D, finally reboot and observe what happens.

I suggest taking very good backups before starting, including an image backup
of the boot drive before doing the partition work of deleting the old D and
resizing C. Only use Disk Management for these operations, no other tool.

While copying D, ensure that you can see all folders and files, including
hidden and system folders and files.

Comment: Thanks!  This worked well so I'm back up and running.  The only issue I ran into was when trying to expand the C: partition to take up the freed up space.  There was an OEM partition in between the two partitions and Disk Management wouldn't let me delete it.  I used the `diskpart` command line utility to delete it then was able to use Disk Management to expand it.